# ArcMap shows error 000539 for NDSI calculation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I want to run Raster Calculator to calculate NDSI from atmospherically corrected Landsat images, but it shows error 000539 and some other errors.

I downloaded bulk data (Landsat collection 2 level-2) from Earth Explorer and used the NDSI formula in Raster Calculator.

The calculation works on the image downloaded from EOS Landviewer but I wanted to use an atmospherically corrected image. I have included a screenshot of the output message.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the calculation as text? What is the name of the output raster (not a `.tif` in a file geodatabase right?)

Comment: Both the geoprocessing command and the error message should always be included in the body of the question as text. This assures that both are legible on all devices and free-text searchable for others to find your Question.